# How to Window.alert when PayPal buy button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I am integrating PayPal Smart buttons using PHP. When Buy button clicked, I want to make window.alert and ask something from user. How can I do it?

Here you see the second script when I write something inside of that one, buttons disappear

this is my script:

```
 <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script> 

<script>

    var name =  "<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>"
    var surname = "<?php echo $_SESSION['surname']; ?>"
    var email_address = "<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>"

    paypal.Buttons({

    createOrder: function(data, actions)
    {
        return actions.order.create
        ({
                purchase_units: [{
                                  amount: {
                                    value: '120'
                                  }
                                }],


                payer: {
                name: {
                    given_name: name,
                    surname: surname
                    },
                    email_address: email_address
                }


        });
    },

    onApprove: function(data, actions) 
    {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) 
        {

            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);

        return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete',
        {
              method: 'post',
              headers: 
              {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify
              ({
                orderID: data.orderID
              })
        });
        });
    },

    onCancel: function (data)
    {   
          alert("You have cancelled the payment!");
          setTimeout("location.href = 'http://localhost/index.php';",100);    
    }

  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  </script>
```

Comment: you need concatenate function .... Function `to display alert()`; `on finish` run function to call `Paypal API`. all in javascript...

Comment: I cannot add any function inside Paypal.Buttons()  function, when I add something buttons disappear

Comment: you need add startting function on click Payment Buton whitout firing Paypal.Buttons() function, instead of it fire and function to alert, when this finish you can concatenate Paypal API Event.

Comment: and i cant see your script.

Comment: I added the all script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, work for me:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>
<script>
    var name = "<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>"
    var surname = "<?php echo $_SESSION['surname']; ?>"
    var email_address = "<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>"
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            alert('you are Creating and Order see all the Content.');
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '120'
                    }
                }],
                payer: {
                    name: {
                        given_name: name,
                        surname: surname
                    },
                    email_address: email_address
                }
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
                return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        orderID: data.orderID
                    })
                });
            });
        },
        onCancel: function(data) {
            alert("You have cancelled the payment!");
            setTimeout("location.href = 'http://localhost/index.php';", 100);
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```